# How to track which user is creating object for a model and how to show the object details only to that user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am doing an online classroom project in Django where I created a model named *create_course* which is accessible by teachers. Now I am trying to design this as the teacher who creates a class only he can see this after login another teacher shouldn't see  his classes and how to add students into that particular class I created

*the course model*

```
class course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course_sec = models.IntegerField()
    classroom_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

here if I use "the created_by" field in forms it appears to be a drop-down menu where every user is showing but I want to automatically save the user who creates the object

*views.py*

```
def teacher_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = add_course(request.POST or None)
    context = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Class Created Sucessfully")
    context['add_courses'] = form
    return render(request, 'teacherview.html', context)
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from .models import course

class add_course(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = course
        fields = ('course_name', 'course_id', 'course_sec', 'classroom_id')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the logged in user to the `.created_by` of the `.instance` in the `form`, so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def teacher_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = add_course(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.created_by = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = add_course()
    return render(request, 'teacherview.html', {'add_courses': form})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `CourseForm` instead of
> <s>`add_course`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`course`</s> to `Course`.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and suggestions .

Answer (score 1):

In your view use commit=False to stop the form from saving until you add the created_by field.

```py
def teacher_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = add_course(request.POST or None)
    context = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        course = form.save(commit=False)
        course.created_by = request.user
        course.save()
        return HttpResponse("Class Created Sucessfully")
    context['add_courses'] = form
    return render(request, 'teacherview.html', context)
```

Comment: I think model `course` should also be in  Pascal case like `Course`, its recommended.